# how to split the pagination based on number of records using angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Iam working with pagination with table.In that how to split the records based on number of records in table .please suggested me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey it would be good if you have mentioned some code anyhow here is the link what will help you. see if possible please paste your code so that somebody can modify and give you. check out this link

[fiddle 1][1]

[fiddle 2][2]

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/16/
  [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/
```